# Get Top activity from service

Tags: java, android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-5.1.1-lollipop

I'm developing custom launcher for terminal (with package name com.my.launcher.Launcher, Terminal OS is Android 5.1.1). And I want to show password dialog to secure activity. For that I launch service and listening opened activities with following code:

```
String activityOnTop = mActivityManager.getRunningTasks(10).get(0).topActivity.getClassName();
Log.d("myLog", "" + activityOnTop);
```

And when I open Settings, instead of getting package name

```
com.android.settings
```

I get this:

```
com.my.launcher.Launcher
```

The same Log with FileManager. But there is my CustomActivity and when I start it Log writes corresponding package name:

```
com.my.launcher.custom.CustomActivity
```

What is I'm doing wrong? Please help!

Comment: @Bakharom Achilov do u want recent Activity right?

Comment: @Moorthy I want to get current opened activity, precisely opened activity's package name